# Setting Head in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to make a Linked List I have a working insert method however I don't know how to set head to the front of the list.

```
public void insert(Object o) {      
    curr = new Link(o,curr);
    if(ticker ==0){
        head = curr;
        tail = curr;
    }
    ticker++;
}
```

This just sets head to the end of the list when it needs to be in the front. Any help would be much appreciated. And if you need anything else to figure this out let me know.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: If I put in a, b, c in that order then head should be pointing to c and tail should be pointing to a.

Comment: You state that you have a working insert method...`insert(0, newHeadObject)`

Comment: This insert method will make the list however it won't set my head and tail properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what your Link is, but I think you should create a Node class like

```
class Node {
   Object value;
   Node next;
   Node pre; // optional
}
```

And your head and tail will be a instance of Node.

Comment: Sorry yes I already have that if you want I can post that code for you so you understand what I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the constructor for `Link`. Based on your result, the new Link stores a reference to the old Link; this is reversed, and thus your list is built in reverse. Set the Link argument's next node to the Link being instantiated, something like

```
public Link(Object value, Link previous) {
    ...
    previous.nextLink = this;
    ...
}
```

The head of a linked list refers to the *first* element that was added, not the last, as you indicated in your comment. That's just the terminology.

You need an `else` branch in your insert method setting `tail = current`, so you always have a reference to the end of the list. (`head` already points to the beginning of the list, and which node is the head won't change) In fact, if you do this, you won't even need the variable `tail`, since `current` will serve the same purpose.

Comment: The only problem is my insert method puts the list in c,b,a order. and head points to a when i do this. How do i re-organize the list so that it is a,b,c and head still points to the beginning?